# Integrate FitNesse/Selenesse into maven build

Tags: maven, selenium-rc, fitnesse

I would like to execute Selenesse test written in FItNesse when I launch maven (mvn clean
install).

I'm using trinidad plug-in to run FitNesse basics tests and it's work fine.

But, if I want to launch selenesse test such as this :

```
| open | MyLink/login.php |
| pause | 5000|
| type; | UserName | ${login}|
| type; | Password | ${password}|
| click |//input[@type='submit']|
|waitForTextPresent|WSQC|
```

it's failed with this error message :

Slim Selenium Driver Could not invoke constructor for
SlimSeleniumDriver[4]

This error is in the SetUp page of my Suite above "Slim Selenium Driver" :

```
!|Import  |
|selenesse|

!|script|
|start|Slim Selenium Driver|${seleniumHost}|${seleniumPort}|${seleniumBrowser}|${baseURL}|
|setTimeoutSeconds|30|
```

If i launch the test from FItNesse wiki it's work fine, But from Maven
i've got this issue. Does anyone have an idea ?

Hope my request is clear.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first thought is some sort of classpath error.  How are your !path variables defined?  Is it possible that the !path entries in your wiki expect the Selenium jar files to be in a specific place, and maven is launching from a different starting point, thus affecting a relative path?

I'm not an expert a Maven, but I would also look at your maven project and make sure that the Selenium jar files are referenced there correctly.

Comment: First thank you for replying. You put me on track with your last sentence.

I just fix the issue. Selenesse.jar is required in fitnesse in order to launch web test.

But, in maven repository there is no selenesse. So i had to find a way to add a dependency to my pom.xml file. So i launched this command :

mvn install:install-file -Dfile=C:\fitnesse\dist\java\selenesse.jar -DgroupId=org.seleniumhq.selenium.selenesse -DartifactId=selenesse -Dversion=1.0 -DgeneratePom=true -Dpackaging=jar

Then i've just to add the dependency in my pom.xml. And.... It worked ! :)